# Как получать ответ от сервера каждую секунду?

Tags: javascript, php

Как получать ответ от сервера каждую секунду? Без цикла все хорошо работает, но со циклом дает ошибку и я не получаю сообщение.
Ошибка:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 7

```php
for ($i = 0; $i<2; $i++){ 
  echo json_encode(['a' => 1]);  
  ob_flush(); 
  flush(); 
}
```

```js
fetch(event.target.action, { 
  method: event.target.method, 
  body: new FormData(event.target) 
}) 
.then(response => response.json()) 
.then(data => { 
  console.log(data) 
}) 
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

То есть, по факту, я должен получать в консоль каждую сек ответ

Comment: Тут больше подойдет ситуация "как отправлять запрос на сервер каждую секунду". ;) Поскольку когда сервер ответит - уже не зависит от клиента...

Comment: аа, ну да. Тогда лучше отправить и получить ответ :)

Comment: А почему ошибка возникает? :(

Comment: Нужно смотреть что отсылает сервер. Его ответ не нравится как JSON...

Comment: так я скинул пхп код вверху

Comment: Я не ПХПист... Тут не подскажу...

Comment: Достаточно посмотреть на то, что возвращает сервер (через drkflre network).... например он может выдать такую фразу "Notice: ob_flush(): Failed to flush buffer. No buffer to flush in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 5"

Comment: Организуйте взаимодействие по сокету, тогда сервер сможет пихать клиенту данные тогда, когда захочет и с любой(условно) скоростью. Каждую итерацию цикла, каждую секунду... по какому то событию, одним словом, когда надо будет, тогда и отправит

Comment: В целом тут цикл нужно делать не на бэке, а на фронте.....либо организовывать связь через сокеты....тогда можно

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так можно отправлять запросы на сервер не ранее одной секунды

```
// стартуем первый раз
test()

function test() {
  fetch(event.target.action, { 
    method: event.target.method, 
    body: new FormData(event.target) 
  }) 
  .then(response => response.json()) 
  .then(data => { 
    console.log(data) 
  }) 
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
  
  // запускаем запрос еще раз
  setTimeout(test, 1000)
}
```

> То есть, по факту, я должен получать в консоль каждую сек ответ

Это далеко не факт, т.к. сильно зависит от загруженности как клиента, так и сервера. Быстродействие интернета или сети так же внесет свою лепту в этот промежуток...

Comment: все равно ошибку получаю

Comment: @jjjjj, так это только отправка... Что присылает сервер я не могу знать...

Comment: так я приложил код пхп

Comment: цикл это и есть ответ от сервера

Comment: @jjjjj, я с ПХП не работаю... Замени `response.json()` на `response.text()` и посмотри что приходит от сервера.

Comment: ```{"a":1}{"a":1}``` вот это мне дало одним текстом

Comment: Даже если я поставлю text, я получу ответ сразу, но ведь у меня flush в php

Comment: @jjjjj, сервер не может "самопроизвольно" отвечать по `http[s]` протоколу... Он может отвечать только на запрос. Сколько запросов - столько и ответов. Я показал в примере как можно спрашивать сервер каждую секунду. Т.о. ты можешь отвечать на приходящие запросы.

Comment: @jjjjj, `{"a":1}{"a":1}` - это не JSON.

Comment: Так он отвечает когда все обработаны

Comment: @jjjjj, меняй свой сценарий работы с сервером. Или меняй возвращаемое значение. Вот так это будет JSON - `[{"a":1},{"a":1}]`.

Comment: У меня просто 300 запросов курлом и я долго получаю ответ и я хочу сдалать preloader и показать, сколько запросов отправлено уже

Comment: чистым пхп все хорошо, я получаю сообщение каждый отправленый запрос, а вот как на js я хз

Comment: @jjjjj, со стороны клиента это может выглядеть так... 1. Отсылается запрос с данными на запуск всего действа. Сервер присылает некий ИД, отвечающий за это. 2. Клиент начинает, с некой периодичностью, опрашивать сервер типа "как дела по такому ИД". Сервер может ответить неким прогрессом или сказать что все готово. На прогресс - клиент рисует его на странице. 3. Если все готово - клиент спрашивает результаты по ИД. Сервер их присылает. Если результаты не нужны - клиент может просто сообщить об этом факте.